# CORS Policy won't work, because all response headers are set, but still getting this error

Tags: java, servlets

I trie to get a response from my POST Method in my Servlet java class. 
I trie to set all headers , but i got always the error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'XXX' from origin 'http://localhost:8080'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

Here are my headers:

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true,urlPatterns = {"/Mitarbeiter_Einzel_Update"})
public class Mitarbeiter_Einzel_Update extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Mitarbeiter_Einzel_Update() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(req, resp);
}

@Override
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");

  [...]

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create servlet Filter to check if the request Method is "OPTIONS"

```
    import javax.servlet.Filter;

    public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req  = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
        //resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.getHeader("Origin"));
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
            resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method"));
            resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
            resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```